# On focus input: insert value and move cursor to end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

#### What I'm aiming for

When the user focuses the input: if it's empty, we insert the prefix text and move the cursor to the end. It should also work if they tab into the input.

#### Context/demo

I'm making a jQuery plugin that adds a flag dropdown next to an telephone number input. When the user focuses the input, it gets populated with a little prefix (the selected country's dial code). [Demo here](http://jackocnr.com/intl-tel-input.html).

#### Problems

By default, the cursor will appear where ever they clicked i.e. potentially in the middle of the prefix). I found [this mini plugin](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/move-cursor-to-end-of-textarea-or-input/) to move the cursor to the end, which works well if you put it in a click event handler, BUT then this wont fire if you tab into the input. I tried putting it in a focus event handler instead, but that didn't work (I think because the click event is fired after the focus event).

#### Bonus points

For a simple, elegant solution, using no global variables, and the least number of event listeners possible. Also if possible, don't show the cursor where they are clicking before moving it to the end.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best solution I have come up with so far. It ticks all the boxes, except it's not the most elegant solution - I feel like I might be missing something obvious. Ideally, it would only require one event listener.

```
var input = $("input"),
  prefix = "prefix ";

input.focus(function(e) {
  if (!input.val()) {
    input.val(prefix);
  }
});

input.mousedown(function(e) {
  // mousedown decides where the cursor goes, so if we're focusing
  // we must prevent this from happening
  if (!input.is(":focus") && !input.val()) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // but this also cancels the focus, so we must trigger that manually
    input.focus();
    putCursorAtEnd(input);
  }
});
```

Here's a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/jackocnr/pen/xuLri).

Comment: This does not work for me in Firefox when using the Tab button the make the input field gain focus. It works perfectly when clicking into the input field. Unfortunately, I'm still searching for a way to do this by tabbing...

Answer (score 0):

## Focus, clear value, then revert to original value

1st save the value to a temporary variable.

2ndly clear the input field

3rdly focus that empty field & again paste the saved value from temporary variable.

it will always focus to the end of the field.

```
$tempVal = $("#digibox_otp").val();
$("#digibox_otp").val('');
$("#digibox_otp").focus().val($tempVal);
```